# How do you gracefully shutdown in Nuxt3

Tags: backend, nuxt3, graceful-degradation

I'm trying to disconnect from the database when the server is shutting down in Nuxt3.
This used to work in Nuxt 2
[image]
but it doesn't work anymore in Nuxt3.
Writing the code in the "ready" hook in nuxt.config.ts doesn't help either.
Also, I tried a simple "console.log('something')" in the "close" hook but didn't appear in the console either when I pressed ctrl+c
Does anyone know how I can do this in Nuxt3?

Comment: I wonder if [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/9219) could be related to what's happening to you.

Comment: The person is using Nuxt2 in the example he gave. It used to work for Nuxt2 but no longer for Nuxt3

Comment: My bad. It still works. It just doesn't work in development environment.